# Existence of certain set triple in certain set system

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of subsets of some finite set $X$, where $\left| X\right|\geq 5$, with the property that for every $a, b, c\in X$ there exists $F\in\mathcal{F}$ with $F\subseteq X\setminus\{a, b, c\}$.

Must there always exist three sets $F, G, H\in\mathcal{F}$, at least two of which are inclusion-maximal in $\mathcal{F}$, and three points $f, g, h\in X$ satisfying $f\in F\setminus{(G\cup H)}$, $g\in G\setminus{(F\cup H)}$ and $h\in H\setminus{(F\cup G)}$?

By "inclusion-maximal in $\mathcal{F}$" I mean an $M\in\mathcal{F}$ such that for $N\in\mathcal{F}$ with $M\subseteq N$ we necessarily have $M=N$.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer is trivial.  Let
$X$ be $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and let $\cal F$ consist of all two-element
subsets of $X$ plus $X$ itself, i.e. $\cal F$ has $1+\binom 52=11$
elements.  If you pick $a,b,c \in X$, then there clearly is an
$F\in\cal F$ with $F \subseteq X \setminus \{a,b,c\}$.

Now, because of $X \in \cal F$, the *only* inclusion-maximal element of
$\cal F$ is $X$.  This means that it's not possible to select three
elements of $\cal F$ of which at least two are inclusion-maximal.